# how to handle complexed type in emf M2M

Tags: model, emf

I am a beginner in EMF M2M. I have a problem using ATL when target model contains complex types. Here is a small example to show it. Assume I transfer from models of Families.ecore(same as ATL website example Faimilies2Persons) to Graph.ecore(the key part is shown below). I want to create a graph where each family member is one node and two nodes are connected if they are both male or female. Then I start with this template as below. As a result each member is one node but meanwhile I get multiple graphs and each graph has only one node. So anyone can give me some help how to put all nodes into one graph? In principle I think this is a very general problem when ATL handles models with hierarchy complex types. Thanks a lot!

```html
module families2graph;
create OUT : graph from IN : Families;

entrypoint rule myrule() {
 to
  t: graph!Graph (
    name <-  'mygraph',
    type <- #Directed

  )
}
rule Member2Female {
 from
  s : Families!Member 
 to
  t1 : graph!Graph (
   nodes <- t2 
  ),
  t2 : graph!Node (
   name <- s.firstName 
  )
}
```

```html
<eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="Graph">
  <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
    <details key="name" value="Graph" />
    <details key="kind" value="elementOnly" />
  </eAnnotations>
  <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="name" lowerBound="1" eType="ecore:EDataType http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2003/XMLType#//String">
    <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
      <details key="kind" value="element" />
      <details key="name" value="name" />
    </eAnnotations>
  </eStructuralFeatures>
  <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="type" lowerBound="1" eType="#//EdgeDirection" unsettable="true">
    <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
      <details key="kind" value="element" />
      <details key="name" value="type" />
    </eAnnotations>
  </eStructuralFeatures>
  <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="nodes" upperBound="-1" eType="#//Node" containment="true" resolveProxies="false">
    <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
      <details key="kind" value="element" />
      <details key="name" value="nodes" />
    </eAnnotations>
  </eStructuralFeatures>
  <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="edges" upperBound="-1" eType="#//Edge" containment="true" resolveProxies="false">
    <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
      <details key="kind" value="element" />
      <details key="name" value="edges" />
    </eAnnotations>
  </eStructuralFeatures>
</eClassifiers>
<eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="Node">
  <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
    <details key="name" value="Node" />
    <details key="kind" value="elementOnly" />
  </eAnnotations>
  <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="connectedEdges" upperBound="-1" eType="#//Edge" resolveProxies="false">
    <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
      <details key="kind" value="element" />
      <details key="name" value="ConnectedEdges" />
    </eAnnotations>
  </eStructuralFeatures>
  <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="properties" upperBound="-1" eType="#//Property" containment="true" resolveProxies="false">
    <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
      <details key="kind" value="element" />
      <details key="name" value="properties" />
    </eAnnotations>
  </eStructuralFeatures>
  <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="name" eType="ecore:EDataType http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2003/XMLType#//String">
    <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
      <details key="kind" value="attribute" />
      <details key="name" value="name" />
    </eAnnotations>
  </eStructuralFeatures>
</eClassifiers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rule `Member2Female` specifies that from a `Member`, two elements will be created: a `Graph` and a `Node`. You have to put the `nodes <-...` part into the `myrule()` entrypoint where your "main" `Graph` element is created. You can try this:

```
module families2graph;
create OUT : graph from IN : Families;

entrypoint rule myrule() {
    to
        t: graph!Graph (
             name <-  'mygraph',
             type <- #Directed,
             nodes <- Families!Member.allInstances()->collect(e | thisModule.Member2Female(e))
        )
}

unique lazy rule Member2Female {
    from
        s : Families!Member 
    to
        t : graph!Node (
            name <- s.firstName 
        )
}
```

The noted line indicates that the `nodes` reference will own the elements generated from all the `Member` instances from a `Families` model.

If you want more details, you can try: https://wiki.eclipse.org/ATL/User_Guide_-_The_ATL_Language and look for the `Journal2Book` rule definition and explanations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With your solution,  I have a new error "Cannot set feature nodes to value [org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.DynamicEObjectImpl@1d664dc8 (eClass: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl@2ad30dee (name: Member) (instanceClassName: null) "  @Vincent Aranege

Comment: I guess the error is due to the noted line which assign instances of Member to nodes.  And currently I am still not so clear is it possible to do something similar with Java or c++ like "newNode=... then nodes.add(newNode) or graph!Graph.nodes[1].name <-....." @Vincent Aranega

Comment: Oups, my bad. I'm not an ATL guru, I'm more a QVTo guy. I modified my answer lazy rule for `Member2Female`. I set the rule to `unique lazy` in order to force its execution with the same input element to give the same result.